# a better expression for 'percentage divided by 100'

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests, programming, percentages

> The function *f(a,x)* returns the value in the array *a* specified by *x*, where *x* is a percentage of the length of the array, divided by 100.

(i.e. x can be any number between 0 and 1, corresponding to a percentage between 0% and 100%)

Examples: if a = [1,2,3,4,5], then f(a, 0.5) = 3; f(a, 0) = 1; f(a, 1) = 5;

Is there a better way to express that some variable is a '*percentage divided by 100*'?

Preferably I am looking for a single word.

Alternatively a phrase, and a single word that can be used later on to reference that phrase.

My first idea was '*fraction*', but I am not sure whether that conveys the concept.

---

Update based on long's answer:

I am looking for a term for the first item in this list:

- ?, [0-1]
- ?, [0-10]
- percent, %, [0-100]
- per mille 0/00 [0-1000]
- basis point, permyriad 0/000, [0-10000]

Comment: Percentages are literally the values between zero and one already. It's just when we use it with the percent sign, we scale it by 100.

Comment: so i could just call it 'percentage' and a reader would understand that to be a value between 0 and 1?

Comment: No, you would need to call it a fraction of the length. Percentages go from 0 to 100. Or, rewrite the function to use a percentage; or maybe even both (x < 1, it's a fraction; 1 < x < 100, it's a percentage)

Comment: Using *percentage* can be confusing easily. *Fraction* is good, e.g. "widget moveto fraction: *Fraction is a real number between 0 and 1. The widget should adjust its view so that the point given by fraction appears at the beginning of the widget.*"

Comment: @ HugoRune: Can you give a numerical example of what f(a,x) is returning. I ask because by definition n % = n/100 & you have stated "x is a percentage....,divided by 100" which means x%/100 = x / 10000.

Comment: if a = [1,2,3,4,5], then f(a,0.5) = 3; f(a,0) = 1; f(a,1) = 5;

Answer (score 12):

In similar circumstances, the term I usually see is 'proportion', or sometimes 'ratio'. You need to clarify your sentence though, how is the reader to know that if the array *a* has five elements and *x = 0.5*, then *f(a,x)* returns the third element of *a* and not the second?

Answer (score 7):

**Normalized to range [0,1].**

This is the usual approach, and you rarely find values normalized to other ranges.

Answer (score 5):

A percent divided by one hundred is a [basis point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_point), or 1 per ten thousand. Like similar units ([percent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage) 0/0, [per mille](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permille) 0/00 etc), it can be expressed as 0/000.

So, you could possibly say *"where x is a basis point value."*

The basis point is also less commonly called [permyriad](http://math.wikia.com/wiki/Permyriad).

EDIT:
If you want to represent a percentage value as a fraction value between 0 and 1, you may perhaps want [decimal fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal#Decimal_fractions). The number 61/100 (61%) can be written as the decimal fraction 0.61.

Comment: Slight misunderstanding: I am looking for a word to describe a value between 0 and 1; a unit that is a 100 times larger than a percent. This basis point is a unit that is a 100 times smaller than a percent, a value between 0 and 10000. Nevertheless very interesting, I did not know these terms before.

Comment: So do you perhaps want [*decimal fraction*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal#Decimal_fractions)? The number 61/100 (61%) can be written as the decimal fraction 0.61. Edit added to answer above.

Comment: That could be it, yes

Comment: @HugoRune When you say that a value between 0 and 1 is 100 times larger than a percent, what exactly do you mean by that?

Answer (score 2):

You can say: ..., where x is a positive proper fraction of the array length.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same naming problem when creating variables/fields for rates in order to disambiguate a number which might be scaled in different ways.

Basis Point and Percentage are clear and unequivocal, but I can't find a good name for the representation where for example 0.1 actually means 10%.

Best I have been able to come up with is "Mathematical", "Formal Decimal" or "Quant Decimal".

Comment: Hi @John, the site prefers that answers be supported. Can you please [edit] your answer to explain why your three suggestions are good answers to the question?

Comment: Hi @Lawrence.  As I said in my entry, I have not been able to find a good answer.  I don't think my suggestions are very good.
The thinking behind "Quant Decimal" is that when interest rates are being manipulated in Quant libraries (in financial firms) a "10%" rate is expressed as "0.1".  
Normalized/Normalised (as suggested above) would be great if it wasn't for the fact that interest rates can be outside the [0,1] range.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. It would be useful to link to such a definition from your answer. Welcome to EL&U, by the way. Have a look at [this post](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10551/142322) about what the site is trying to achieve by requiring answers to be supported.