# A number between 0 and 1 - like a percentage but expressed as a decimal

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I'm looking for a word to replace "percentage" for numbers between 0 and 1.

To explain: what I'm actually dealing with are decimals (like `0.12`), semantically however they serve the purpose of percentages (the equivalent here being `12%`, obviously).

So my number between 0 and 1 is not a percentage but a _______. Any ideas?

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140120/a-better-expression-for-percentage-divided-by-100) is similar, but has a different focus; it allows for multiple words, whereas mine needs a single word.

Comment: Note that [“naming, including naming programming variables/classes” are off-topic on this site](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I don't understand. In programming, you can name the variables whatever you want. So what exactly is wrong with naming it percent, percentage, prcnt, frct, myLittlePart, etc...?

Comment: *proportion* is one commonly used term for this (as one of the answers to the linked question points out.). If they represent probabilities, use that.

Comment: @EFrog: If you name it _percent_, don't come complaining if I jam a value of 27.5 in your variable and break your code. In _good_ programming, you give your variables a meaningful name.

Comment: @oerkelens "Percent" would be quite the meaningful name, considering that's *exactly* what it is. If that name is already taken in the namespace, however, then obviously it's a bad choice. My point was that you can choose *anything* as your variable's name. Anyway, my suggestion is *grade*.

Comment: @EFrog: if, as the OP states, a value of 0.12 represents 12%, then _percent_ is a terrible name for your variable. If the value 12 would represent 12%, it would be very meaningful. And naming variables anything you feel like just because you can is a terrible idea and the most common reason why programmers want to kill their predecessors.

Comment: @oerklens We can do this all day. If you feel that your variable's name could be misunderstood in any way, there's usually a way to comment (also a *good* programming practice) to make notes of what certain functions and variables are for. And 12% is 12/100 is .12. It makes *sense*. 12 isn't at all equal to 12%; it's equal to 1200%. I would assume programmers know how basic math works.

Comment: @EFrog So if on a website that you have to fill out, titled, for example, “Density (in percent)”, you would write “0.12” and expect that to mean a density of 12%? That may make sense to a mathematician, but it makes no sense to me. If a variable named _percent_ or _percentage_ is _0.12_, the natural assumption is that it represents 0.12%, or 0.0012.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Ok, now we're talking about user-input, which is different from other programmers using your code. If you're expecting a user to input a percentage, then A) it doesn't matter *what* you name the variable in-code because the user never sees it, and B) you should either assume that the user is going to interpret that they should input 12 (so put a "divide by 100" in your code) or explain to the user that they should do that themselves...

Comment: @EFrog The user input analogy was simply to make the distinction clearer. The latter half of the comment is not user input-related. If you’re going through someone else’s code and you see a variable named _percentage_, you will expect the value of that variable to be a percentage, not a decimal fraction. (Discussions like this is why variable naming is off-topic here, incidentally, because they’re not about the English language at all.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet If you go through someone's code and see a variable named `ratio` are you expecting to assign it the value `1:10`, or `proportion` the value `3 to 5`? Along with the variable name isn't some random cloud of ambiguity. It's accompanied by *context* as well as an *example*. And as I stated previously, you can comment it all you like to avoid any confusion. Sometimes there isn't an exact word for what you're looking for. (And I agree.)

Comment: All possible numbers 0 to 1 are called _unit interval_ so not only is this off topic, it's also general reference at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_interval and for the first time ever I'm voting to close a question.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet thank you for letting me know, it's not a practice I'm interested in repeating. But regardless of whether it's a variable name or not, as a linguist I'd like to know whether there's a good answer.

Comment: @Frank Fulfil your civic duty! (Remember W C Fields who answered 'Who am I votin' for? I never vote _for_ politicians, I vote _against_ 'em!'

Comment: I have taken the liberty of editing the question to remove references to programming and variables, which makes the question on-topic. @Frank, just because you can find something (if you know where to look) on Wikipedia doesn’t mean it’s necessarily general reference. _Unit interval_ is not defined in any of the online dictionaries I just tried, and even if it were, GR goes the other way: asking “What does X mean?” is GR if you can look up the word in a source made for it, but asking “Is there a word for X?” is not general reference just because the answer is in the dictionary/on Wikipedia.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  Without the variable naming it's now just a maths question and should be asked on a maths site. Closest thing to a dictionary I know of for maths is Wolfram Mathworld  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UnitInterval.html My close vote stays.

Comment: *So my number between 0 and 1 is not a percentage but a* **number**.  If you want be more precise, it's a "decimal fraction".

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet http://verizonmath.blogspot.com/ :)

Comment: I call these a portion. A portion is a part of the whole. It makes sense to me that the whole is 1. and that 0.5 would half of the whole.

Comment: This question keeps popping up, and my conclusion is that there just isn't a good and well-established English name for these numbers. So for my own coding, I'm making up my own word: [unidecimal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2489/is-there-a-name-for-0-1/4400548#4400548). :-)

Comment: OP here: for what it's worth, I'm still using the word `proportion` to refer to this, years later, thanks to some of the comments and answers here.

Answer (score 22):

Numbers between 0 and 1 are **fractions,** and fractions expressed as a decimal are ***decimal fractions.***

> **decimal fraction**
>
> a fraction (as .25 = <sup>25</sup>⁄<sub>100</sub> or .025 = <sup>25</sup>⁄<sub>1000</sub>) or mixed number (as 3.025 = 3<sup>25</sup>⁄<sub>1000</sub>) in which the denominator is a power of 10 usually expressed by use of the decimal point.
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decimal%20fraction)

Comment: *Ratio* might also be appropriate.

Comment: @KitFox: with _ratio_ my first question is of _what_ to _what_? It seems in this case, the answer is always _something to one_. It _is_ a ratio, but not very meaningful...

Comment: As *fractions* may be proper (numerator less than denominator) or improper, it may be helpful to qualify the numbers between 0 and 1 as *proper fractions*. The improper fraction 7/3 is by definition a fraction; however, it is not between 0 and 1.

Comment: Nice answer but two words ...

Comment: Or the word “proportion,” meaning “a number considered in comparative relation to a whole.”

Answer (score 5):

**From a pure linguistics perspective, the answer is *"percent"*.**

> In mathematics, a percentage is a number or ratio expressed as a fraction of 100.
>   <sup>[[wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage)</sup>

0.12 and 12% are as equivalent, as 0.1234 and 12.34% are. If the numbers you are expressing are proportional then *percent* is as valid as anything else.

---

**Off-topic answer:**

However, you question wasn't about linguistics, it was about naming variables in which case percent/ration/unit are all **terrible variable names**. When naming variables, succinctness is of far less importance than readability. Variable names can be minimised or optimised by the complier, as a programmer your role is writing human readable code first, and machine readable code second.

As a programmer, the variable name should have some better context than a unitless proportion, so re-evaluate what you are storing, determine what the actual value means, and try again (probably on Programmers.SE).

Comment: So, to summarize, what would you recommend to name a variable?

Comment: you could simply call it a "probability of 0.5", a number between 0 and 1 can be used as a probability, the % is only to imply a fraction of 100, as in "probability of 50%", the ratio of 50/100 is exacly 0.5

Comment: OP here: FWIW I don't remember exactly but my question was probably about the extent to which something (e.g. an animation) has been completed, like `animation.proportionCompleted`. The issue with `progress` and with `percent` is that "progress" has no unit specification at all, and "percent" seems to be between 0 and 100. I think that's why I was looking for something succinct here